# JavaFX - Removing the black line under the tabs in a tab pane

Tags: javafx

I have a black line under my tab pane. The line is always there and goes from the most left pixel of the first tab a few pixels to the right of the last tab.

I've tried so many CSS selectors now and went through all of the listed selectors in the JavaFX 8 Oracle documentation and I have no idea what causes the black line to be there. I've not seen it ony the many other examples regarding the tab pane here.

It is always there, even when I remove all of my prior styling.

[image]

How can I remove it?

Comment: https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view

Comment: @Oleksandr Looks nice I'll give it a try as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into the default caspian.css file embedded into the jfxrt.jar.

This is defined there for the headers-region class:

```css
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-style: segments(0.166667em, 0.166667em);
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-focus-color;
}
```

It can be overriden by using:

```css
.tab-header-area > .headers-region {
    -fx-border-width: 0;
```

Results in:

[image]